# React+Redux: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and redux.I am building a simple E-Commerce app with React/Redux and Django.I am facing a problem which I cant get.The Problem is whenever I hit place order button, it is showing me **Request failed with status code 500**[here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwTOY.png) as message in the app. Redux inspector in the browser is showing ORDER_CREATE_FAIL [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzQL6.png) constant.But the API is pasing data in the database but not redirecting to /order/${order._id} page.Why is this happening.And What is the solution?

**PlaceOrderScreen.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Button,Row,Col,ListGroup,Image,Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps'
import { createOrder } from '../actions/orderActions'


function PlaceOrderScreen({ history }) {
    
    const orderCreate = useSelector(state=>state.orderCreate)
    const { order, error ,success} = orderCreate
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const cart = useSelector(state =>state.cart)
    
    cart.itemsPrice = cart.cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0)
    cart.shippingPrice = cart.shippingAddress.city === ('Dhaka' || 'dhaka') ? 50 : 120
    cart.taxPrice = Number((0.015) * cart.itemsPrice)
    
    cart.totalPrice=Number(cart.itemsPrice) + Number(cart.shippingPrice) + Number(cart.taxPrice)
    
    if(!cart.paymentMethod){
        history.push('/payment')
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(success){
            history.push(`/order/${order._id}`)
        }
    }, [success,history])
    
    const placeOrder = () =>{
        dispatch(createOrder({
            orderItems:cart.cartItems,
            shippingAddress:cart.shippingAddress,
            paymentMethod:cart.paymentMethod,
            itemsPrice:cart.itemsPrice,
            shippingPrice:cart.shippingPrice,
            taxPrice:cart.taxPrice,
            totalPrice:cart.taxPrice,
            
        }))
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 step4 />
            <Row>
                <Col md={8}>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <h2>Shipping</h2>
                            
                            <p>
                                <strong>Shipping to: {cart.shippingAddress.address}, {cart.shippingAddress.city}</strong>
                                {'  '}
                                {cart.shippingAddress.postalCode},
                                {'  '}
                                {cart.shippingAddress.country},
                                {'  '}
                                Phone: {cart.shippingAddress.phone}
                            </p>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <h2>Payment Method</h2>                            
                            <p>
                                <strong>Payment: </strong>
                                {cart.paymentMethod}
                               
                            </p>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <h2>Order Items</h2>                            
                            {cart.cartItems.length === 0 ? <Message variant='info'>
                                Your cart is empty
                             </Message> : (
                                 <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                                     {cart.cartItems.map((item, index)=>(
                                         <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                                             <Row>
                                                <Col md={1}>
                                                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded/>
                                                </Col>
                                                
                                                <Col>
                                                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                                                </Col>
                                                
                                                <Col md={4}>
                                                    {item.qty} X ৳{item.price} = ৳{(item.qty * item.price)}
                                                </Col>
                                             </Row>
                                         </ListGroup.Item>
                                     ))}
                                 </ListGroup>
                             )}
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        
                    </ListGroup>
                
                </Col>
                
                <Col md={4}>
                    <Card>
                        <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                               <h2>Order Summary</h2>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                               <Row>
                                   <Col>Item:</Col>
                                   <Col>৳{cart.itemsPrice}</Col>
                               </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                               <Row>
                                   <Col>Shipping Charge:</Col>
                                   <Col>৳{cart.shippingPrice}</Col>
                               </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                               <Row>
                                   <Col>VAT 1.5%:</Col>
                                   <Col>৳{cart.taxPrice}</Col>
                               </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                               <Row>
                                   <Col>Total:</Col>
                                   <Col>৳{cart.totalPrice}</Col>
                               </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                               <Button
                                   type='button'
                                   className='btn-black'
                                   disabled={cart.cartItems === 0}
                                   onClick={placeOrder}
                               >
                                    Place Order
                               </Button>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlaceOrderScreen
```

**orderActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { 
    ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST, 
    ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
    ORDER_CREATE_FAIL 
    } from '../constants/orderConstants'

    export const createOrder = (order) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
        try{
            dispatch({
                type:ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST
            })
            
            const {
                userLogin: { userInfo },
            } = getState()
            
            const config={
                headers:{
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization : `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` //Authorization Token 
                }
            }
            
            const {data} = await axios.post(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/add/',
                order,
                config,
                )
            
            dispatch({
                type:ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
                payload:data
            })
                    
            
        }catch(error){
            dispatch({
                type:ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
                payload:error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                :error.message,
            })
        }
    }
```

**orderReducers.js**

```
import { ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST, 
         ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
         ORDER_CREATE_FAIL 
         } from '../constants/orderConstants'

export const orderCreateReducer = (state={}, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST:
            return {
                loading:true
            }
            
        case ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading:false,
                success:true,
                order:action.payload
            }
            
        case ORDER_CREATE_FAIL:
            return {
                loading:false,
                error:action.payload
            }
            
        default:
            return state
            
        
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, so what is your problem? you want fix the bug?

Comment: hello!yes! I want to fix the bug. Why the page is not redirecting to /order/${order._id} ?

Comment: Unless the frontend is sending the wrong parameters, I don't see that this is a frontend problem. The first thing you need to establish is why the backend returns a 500 server error. You need to look in the devtools of your browser at the network panel and locate the failing request. You need to establish if that request is being made as expected (i.e. with right data). If it is, then you need to refocus on the backend to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Okay ..I am Trying to find out the backend bug. Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I have solve the issue in the way you told me. thank you very much. Big thumbs up! In Backend I had a field '_id' but I was running my querie as 'id' that was the issue!